# search strings across attributes with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have different attributes which contains identical text strings. Like:

```
<div id="outer">
<div id="carousel-example-generic"></div>
<div data-target="#carousel-example-generic"></div>
<a href="#carousel-example-generic" ></a>
</div>
```

How do I find and rename "carousel-example-generic" on those elements using jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
$(document.documentElement).html(function(i,val){
    return val.replace(/carousel-example-generic/g,'my-new-string');
});
```

...but be careful, this will replace the string *everywhere* in the document: tags, text, values, *everywhere*. Also, as Salman says below, event handlers are also destroyed, including those of parent elements.

Given your example above, the code shown here yields the following html:

```
<div id="outer">
<div id="my-new-string">asdfasdf</div>
<div data-target="#my-new-string">asdfadsfad</div>
<a href="#my-new-string">asdfasdfa</a>
</div>
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x55q5p1s/4/). Examine the elements to see the changes.

Comment: It will also destroy content and replace it with identical looking, but not the same content.

Comment: Run this script on _this_ page, then post a comment, if you can.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following. Can you provide a small example? Maybe there's an adjustment needed to the code.

Comment: When you replace the inner html with something, the existing elements including their event handlers are destroyed. E.g. if you attach click handler to #outer then your code will destroy it (even though outer was not supposed to be touched).

Answer (score 0):

The following is one approach:

```
// iterates over each of the descendant elements of '#outer':
$('#outer *').each(function() {
  // iterates over the array-like 'this.attributes' (list of the element's attributes)
  // property, using Array.prototype.forEach, 'a' is the array-element itself:
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.attributes, function(a) {
    // setting the value of the attribute:
        // if the string 'carousel-example-generic' is found within the attribute-value,
        // we replace that string with 'new-string', otherwise
        // return the current attribute-value:
    a.value = a.value.indexOf('carousel-example-generic') > -1 ? a.value.replace('carousel-example-generic', 'new-string') : a.value;
  });
});
```

```js
$('#outer *').each(function() {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.attributes, function(a) {
    a.value = a.value.indexOf('carousel-example-generic') > -1 ? a.value.replace('carousel-example-generic', 'new-string') : a.value;
  });
});

$('#result').text($('#outer').html());
```

```css
#result {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  font-family: monospace;
  border: 1px solid #f90;
  margin-top: 1em;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
#result::before {
  content: 'HTML converted to:';
  border: 1px solid #f90;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1em;
  left: 0.5em;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding: 0 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outer">
  <div id="carousel-example-generic"></div>
  <div data-target="#carousel-example-generic"></div>
  <a href="#carousel-example-generic"></a>

</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`Element.attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.attributes).
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
  - [`String.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).
- jQuery:

  - [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).